# Gdb macro: 64 bit variable

Tags: gdb

I am using gdb macro for debugging. 
My system under debugging is 64 bit intel processor. Varable under debugging is storing a 64 bit value.

In macro while storing variable values, value is stored as 32 bit. 
For example following prints only 32 bit from int64temp.

```
set $val = $int64temp

printf "value %d   \n",$val,
```

What change is needed to make variable as 64 bit so that printf give me 64 bit value?
Note: I did set arc by running --

```
set architecture i386:x86-64
```

Answer (score 1):

> printf "value %d   \n",$val

That prints $val as an `int` (which is 32-bit even in 64-bit mode). Try

```
printf "value %ld\n", $val
```

Comment: Thanks but problem seems to be in copy dues to 64 bit arc which result in 32 bit copy